# Magento 2 Blank Layout Page

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, page-layouts, admin-controller

I tried to create a new tab in customer edit backend.

First i create the 
**app/code/Namespace/Point/view/adminhtml/layout/customer_index_edit.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
           <referenceBlock name="customer_form">
             <block class="Namespace\Point\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\CustomerPoint" name="customer_edit_tab_customerpoint" >
              <action method="setTabLabel">
                  <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Namespace Point</argument>
              </action>
            </block>
          </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

then i create the block:

**app/code/Namespace/Point/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Tab/CustomerPoint.php**

```
namespace Namespace\Point\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab;
use Magento\Customer\Controller\RegistryConstants;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Layout\Tabs\TabInterface;

class CustomerPoint extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template implements TabInterface
{

    protected $_coreRegistry; 

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCustomerId()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry(RegistryConstants::CURRENT_CUSTOMER_ID);
    }

    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __("Namespace Point");
    }

    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Namespace Point');
    }

    public function canShowTab()
    {
        if ($this->getCustomerId()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function isHidden()
    {
        if ($this->getCustomerId()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function getTabClass()
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function getTabUrl()
    {
      return $this->getUrl('namespace_point/customerpoint/tab', ['customer_id'=>$this->getCustomerId(),'_current' => true]);
    }

    public function isAjaxLoaded()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

at this point the tab is showing in customer edit admin. Then i create the route **app/code/Namespace/Point/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route frontName="namespace_point" id="namespace_point">
            <module before="Magento_Backend" name="Namespace_Point"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

then the controller **app/code/Namespace/Point/Controller/Adminhtml/Customerpoint/Tab.php**

```
namespace Namespace\Point\Controller\Adminhtml\CustomerPoint;

class Tab extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index
{

    public function execute()
    {
      $this->initCurrentCustomer();
      $resultLayout = $this->resultLayoutFactory->create();
      return $resultLayout;
    }
}
```

then i create layout for this controller layout
**app/code/Namespace/Point/view/adminhtml/layout/namespace_point_customerpoint_tab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <container name="root" label="Root">
        <block class="Namespace\Point\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\CustomerPoint" name="point.edit.tab.customerpoint"  template="Namespace_Point::customer_point_tab.phtml" cacheable="false"/> 
    </container>
</layout>
```

and finally the templates file **app/code/Namespace/Point/view/adminhtml/templates/customer_point_tab.phtml**

```
<h1> POINT </h1>
```

but when i click the new customer tab, it gives me blank page, when i use the tab url in my browser, it gives me blank page too, when i add `die('test');`  at the controller it prints `test` but when i add `die('test');` in the block constructor it gives blank page, seems like the controller doesn't read the xml layout file to generate

Comment: please correct this :  from = `* @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry; ` To = `/* @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry; `

Comment: @kunj sorry its typo, but still not working

Comment: Try after cache flush and di compile, it is working for me but it will display only on customer edit not in customer create

Comment: I have updated answer

Answer (score 0):

please correct this:

your layout should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <container name="root" label="Root">
            <block class="Namespace\Point\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\CustomerPoint" name="point.edit.tab.customerpoint"  template="Namespace_Point::customer_point_tab.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
        </container>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Try after cache flush and di compile, it is working for me but it will display only on customer edit not in customer create